# Stopping IIS Application Pool: are in-flight requests drained?

Tags: iis, application-pools

Is there any *official* documentation on what happens with in-flight requests when an IIS Application Pool is stopped (either from withing the UI or programmatically)?

I suspect that an AppPool is "gracefully" stopped, draining all active requests, but I'd love to have my slightly-educated-guess confirmed.